# How can I write LMS logs to file in Open edX devstack?

Tags: devstack, openedx, edx

Open edX uses to write logs files on `/edx/var/log` but in the LMS docker instance all folders in this path are empty and the only file I've found ('tracking.log`) is empty too.

I can see logs output with `make lms-logs` command on devstack but I want log files written on disk as it would be on a production environment.

I'm running `hawthorn` version and I've not done any change yet.

How can I enable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not wrong Open edX does `devstack` does not record log files in `/edx/var/log` support. And `rsylog` is also not running on the containers.

If you really want to do, there is a tricky way to enable it with custom changes in several places. Before that,

**As you know any changes in containers are not persistent. Once you restart the containers you have to start `rsylog` again**

First,
start `rsylog` in `lms` container

```
make lms-shell
service rsyslog status
service rsyslog start
```

Then check the log listen socket is enabled in `/dev` folder inside the LMS container.

```
ls /dev/log -l
```

If you can see `/dev/log`, then you have to add a few changes to your `edx-platform/lms/envs/devstack_docker.py` file to enable logging.

```
from openedx.core.lib.logsettings import get_logger_config



LOCAL_LOGLEVEL = "INFO"
SERVICE_VARIANT = os.environ.get('SERVICE_VARIANT', None)
LOGGING_ENV = 'sandbox'
LOG_DIR = "/edx/var/log/edx"

LOGGING = get_logger_config(LOG_DIR,
                            logging_env=LOGGING_ENV,
                            local_loglevel=LOCAL_LOGLEVEL,
                            service_variant=SERVICE_VARIANT)
```

Then create empty log files in the LMS container

```
/edx/var/log/edx/lms/edx.org
/edx/var/log/edx/cms/edx.org
/edx/var/log/tracking/tracking.log
```

Now you can check the logs, `tail /edx/var/log/edx/lms/edx.org` and you will see,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's strongly not recommended to use Devstack for a production environment. it's unstable and only for developing purposes. So you can [setup a native openedx instance](https://openedx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OpenOPS/pages/146440579/Native+Open+edX+Ubuntu+16.04+64+bit+Installation) then you can access the log files under `/edx/var/logs/`. but if you are sure about using Devstack, you may find log messages this way:

```sh
docker-compose logs --no-color --tail=1000 CONTAINER_NAME > logs.txt
```

Comment: I don't want to use devstack for a production environment I just want the log files written under /edx/var/log as in a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

@Mahyar Damavand , is there some way to write that logs to Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the settings (lms/envs/devstack_docker.py)

```
LOGGING['handlers']['tracking'] = {
    'level': 'DEBUG',
    'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
    'filename': '/edx/var/log/tracking/tracking.log',
    'formatter': 'raw',
}

LOGGING['loggers']['tracking']['handlers'] = ['tracking']
```